# REST API requests not working with heroku and mLab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, heroku

So when run locally the requests run fine, but online they do not change the data in the database. So for example this request:

```
PUT app.herokuapp.com/api/user/9y0962h5234uih568980
Body(raw):{
  "role": "cat"

}
```

Sent from postman will just return this:

```
{
    "_id": "9y0962h5234uih568980",
    "name": "Doug Polk",
    "active": false,
    "__v": 0,
    "role": "Client"
}
```

Whereas the role should have changed.
Here is the put request code:

```
router.put('/user/:id', function(req, res, next){

  User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body, {new: true}).then(function(){
    User.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(function(user){
      res.send(user);

    });
  }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
});
```

Thanks, Ed.

Comment: *"when run locally the requests run fine, but online they do not change the data in the database"* So what has changed here? At a guess your database connection. Locally you probably connected to localhost, or maybe even picked up an environment variable and even pointed to a remote database. So you are either still pointing to the local database, or your heroku configuration is missing the environment variable pointing to the remote database. Basic point is, take a good hard look at the things that are different. Odds are on it's the database connection. There should be logs that show this.

Comment: Turn on debugging in mongoose with `mongoose.set('debug', true)` around the same place you are making the connection. [View your heroku logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs) and see what is being issued to the database and/or any errors that are present. Then add to your question. You need to provide a lot more information than *"works okay locally"*. Like I said, something has changed. You need to look at the things that have changed.

Comment: Third time now. [There is an Edit Link On Your Question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44859630/edit). Please put your details in there. Also, you don't need to report back with every minor detail. Do some investigation. A Query is being issued, so now connect to the same database yourself and try and find the same data. Try and find anything in it in fact. Did you possibly create a new database different to what you are using locally? And then did you put anything in it? There are lots of logical steps here. Please do some work and write your findings into your question please.